# How do I jump to XML resources in Eclipse instead of R.java

Tags: android, eclipse

- Eclipse version: Indigo Service Release 2
- ADT version: 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762

I have the following code in Eclipse

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.somelayoutfile, parent, false);
```

I want to perform some action, like CTRL+Click on "R.layout.somelayoutfile" and it jump to that xml file. Instead it takes me to "R.java."

According to this the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adt.html) this should be supported, but it doesn't work. Does anyone know why, and/or how to enable this feature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you hold Ctrl with the pointer over the resource name (somelayoutfile in your example) then a menu should appear, with two options:

- Open declaration
- Open declaration in layout/somelayoutfile.xml

That isn't working for you? Or you want the default (direct click on the resource name) to be the second option?

Comment: I did not even see that; how do I make it the default option in Eclipse? I'm accepting this answer because that's something I can likely figure out. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I made a quick check in the android preferences, but didn't see any option to set that.

Comment: I can't seem to find it. I'll keep looking. Worse case I'll post another SO question

Comment: Did you find solution how to make second option default? Right now it's pretty annoying.

Comment: Who needs the "Open declaration" to open R.java???Why they set it as the default option?

Comment: That's how they are telling you to move to Android Studio.

Comment: to to remove the first option i.e. `Open declaration`

Answer (score 17):

The most efficient way.
Eclipse settings - `Hyperlinking` - `Open Declaration` - uncheck.
<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> will start to navigate you directly to XML instead of R class.

[image: Eclipse hyperlinking settings]

You'll still be able to use the `Open Declaration` by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd>.

Comment: Or change the shortcut to `Alt + command`. Pretty useful if you need to open declaration of a field/variable, while still achieving the same result (not opening R.java on command + click). :)

Comment: This must be the accepted answer because it is more detailed.

Answer (score 5):

You Can Use Ctrl+Alt+Shift and click on res

or on Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Hyperlinking you can change shortcut key

Answer (score 0):

`CTRL + CLICK` is the correct way to do that, but sometimes it doesn't work correctly, I don't know why. It's aggravating, I know. If I were you, I'd try one or both things below.

Usually I'll clean my project and if that doesn't fix it, then I'll restart Eclipse and then clean again. One of those two will typically do the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down `ctrl` (or `command` on Mac) THEN move your cursor over the resource name. If you move your cursor to the resource name, and then hit `ctrl`, it will not underline the resource name and will not provide a link. You have to hit `ctrl` and then move the cursor.